# ng-repeat | place a item first if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to place an item in first position depending on a certain condition ? Here i've got a list of 'questions'

```
<ul class="list-group" data-toggle="items" >
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="ques in questions">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="addRemove(ques)" ng-checked="selected.indexOf(ques) != -1" /> {{ques.question}}
        <span ng-if="ques.description">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" title="{{ques.description}}"></i>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've a question which is "None" and I would like to display it in first position.

Thanks !

Comment: You can probably achieve this with ordering. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: I don't really see how it's possible with order by ... Order by + if ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

orderBy with custom sort function

```js
 angular.module('app', []).
  controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
      $scope.items = ['a','b','None','d','e'];

      $scope.custom_sort = function(pred){
        if(pred === 'None') return 1;
      }
  }])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:custom_sort">
          {{item}}
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

After loading your data, you can check for that condition and insert the "None" question at the first position. I'd do that in the controller code (in the `.success(function(data) { ... }` block.

Comment: So I should delete it and push it first ? Any idea how ?

Comment: If the "None" question is already in the array of the returned data, you may just want to use the javascript sort function http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp where you can implement your own sorting strategy

Comment: Forgot that function :/ I will try to find how to sort now